# How to Integrate $ \int \sin^2x\cos\ x \ dx $ without substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I calculate the following integral without using substitution?

$$
\int \sin^2x\,\cos\ x \, dx
$$

I have been stuck on this problem for about a day and cannot seem to come to a conclusion.

Comment: Substitution is probably the best way to solve this - why would you like to avoid it?

Comment: @B.Mehta I realize substitution is the best way to solve this and I am fully aware of how to solve it using substitution, however my professor wanted us to attempt to solve this without using substitution. My original thought was to use a half-angle formula on the $\sin^2x$ but I was not entirely sure what to do to the $\cos x$ (if I had to do anything special to it or not)

Answer (score 4):

Using the equality $\cos  x=D_x(\sin\, x)$ we can see that the integral $\int \sin^2x\cdot\cos  x \, dx$ is equal to integral $\int \sin^2x \cdot D_x(\sin\, x) \, dx$. That is
$$
\int \sin^2x\cdot\cos  x \, dx
=
\int \sin^2x \cdot D_x(\sin\, x) \, dx
$$
Now we can apply the formula of 'integration by parts'
$$
\int \sin^2x\cdot\cos  x \, dx
=
\int \sin^2x \cdot D_x(\sin\, x) \, dx
=
\sin^2x \cdot\sin\, x-\int D_x(\sin^2x)\cdot\sin\, x \, dx
$$
By $D_x(\sin^2x)= 2\cdot \sin x\cdot D_x(\sin x)=2\cdot\sin x\cos x$ we have 
$$
\int \sin^2x\cdot\cos  x \, dx
=
\sin^2x \cdot\sin\, x-\int D_x(\sin^2x)\cdot\sin\, x \, dx
=
\sin^3x-\int 2\cdot\sin x\cdot\cos x \cdot\sin\, x \, dx
$$
and
$$
\int \sin^2x\cdot\cos  x \, dx
=
\sin^3x-2\int \sin^2\, x \cdot\cos x \, dx
$$
Then we have
$$
\int \sin^2\, x \cdot\cos x \, dx = \frac{1}{3}\sin^3 x
$$

Comment: Do you mind clarifying the process in words? I don't fully understand the process here?

Comment: @TheStandardModel, I clarify the process in words.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer making it complicated, the other way consists in linearising the integrand:
\begin{align}
\sin^2x\cos x&=\frac12(1-\cos 2x)\cos x=\frac12(\cos x-\cos 2x\cos x)\\
&=\frac12\Bigl(\cos x -\frac12\bigl(\cos(2x+x)+\cos(2x-x)\bigl)\Bigr)\\
&=\frac14(\cos x-\cos 3x).
\end{align}

Comment: While this seems to make sense looking at the calculations, wouldn't the answer have to be same as if you had arrived at it using the substitution method? In which would be $\frac 13 \ sin^3x$ ?

Comment: @K.Appiah: You're. I confess I didn't check it led  to the same result. I fixed the error in the last line. Thank you for pointing it!

Answer (score 0):

Identify the integral as one of the form

$$\int f'f^n\,dx=\frac{f^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

This is an-almost immediate integral.

Answer (score 0):

Use $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$:

$$I=\int\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\sin(x)\big(\frac{1}{2}(2\sin(x)\cos(x))\big)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\sin(x)\sin(2x)\,dx$$

Two iterations of IBP yields:
$$I=-\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{1}{2}\cos(x)\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{2}I\bigg]$$

Which becomes:
$$I=\frac{4}{3}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\cos(x)\sin(2x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)\cos(2x)\Big)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \sin^2x\,\cos\ x \, dx =\int \frac13(\sin^3x)'\,\cos\ x \, dx =\frac13\sin^3x+c$$